# How to search of specified Extension files on ftp server?

Tags: c#, search, ftp

how to make function supports parameters for this

```
 public List<string> getfiles(string FTPhostname, string FTPpath,string FTPusername,string FTPpassword,string extension)
{
 'request to ftp hostname 
 'get response from 
 'list all directories and files
 'search for spesified extension files
}
```

any way for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the solution a function that return List

```
 public List<string> getfiles(string FTPhostname, string FTPpath,string FTPusername,string FTPpassword,string extension)
    {
        FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + FTPhostname + "/" + FTPpath );
        ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(FTPusername , FTPpassword );
        ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory; 

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

        List<string> results = new List<string>();

        string line = streamReader.ReadLine();
        while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
        {

            if (line.Contains(extension)) {
                line = streamReader.ReadLine();
                results.Add(line);}

            else {line = streamReader.ReadLine(); }
                           }

        streamReader.Close();
        return results;
    }
```

then call this function for ex: `png` files

```
  String[] txtfounds= getfiles("ftp.piacton.com", "/Public/Software/Official/LightField/Archives/", "anonymous", "k3tnel31@k.com", ".png").ToArray();
```

if you want to add this result to lisbox :

```
listBox1.DataSource = txtfounds;
```

Comment: Use `using` for the response & stream.

Comment: Use an iterator instead of pre-loading results.

Comment: @SLaks yeah but on ftp there is no System.IO and this it works perfect

Answer (score 0):

There is an error, you need to do the

```
results.Add(line);
```

before you call the

```
results.Add(line);
```

to get the correct files.

Comment: this should be sad in a comment ! this is not a full answer so dont post a comment as an answer ! and thanks